# Why are WeakRef polyfills made with WeakMap? I don't see how that can work

Tags: javascript, weak-references, polyfills, weakmap

If you look at [both](https://github.com/jaenster/weakref-pollyfill/blob/master/src/index.js) of [these](https://github.com/ungap/weakrefs/blob/master/esm/index.js) examples of `WeakRef` polyfills, they both use `WeakMap`.

But I don't see how that can work. A `WeakMap` doesn't hold weak references to its *values*, but to its *keys*. And both those polyfills use `this` as the key. Which means if I say `let weakRef = new WeakRef(targetObject)`, then `targetObject` will never get garbage collected unless I throw away `weakRef`. Which negates the entire purpose of `WeakRef`, doesn't it?

In my limited experimentation my theory seems to be correct. Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59tjc36e/1/).

Furthermore, does anyone know a `WeakRef` polyfill that *does* work?

Comment: "then targetObject will never get garbage collected unless I throw away weakRef" Isn't that what you want a weak reference to do? When you no longer have a reference to the object, then it will be garbage collected.

Comment: No, the point of a `WeakRef` is that you can hold a reference to an object (so that you can access it when you want) that does not prevent that object from being garbage collected if nothing else holds a reference to that object anymore. What you are describing is exactly how normal references work.

Comment: Well, it may be that the polyfills exist so that code that wants `WeakRef` references can at least *work* in environments that don't support *real* `WeakRef` objects. In other words, there may not be a way to implement the feature in the language itself, but only in the innards of the runtime.

Comment: @Pointy Ah shit, I didn't think of that. Yeah maybe that's true.

Comment: [Here's an old but interesting discussion about the feature.](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/what-is-the-status-of-weak-references)

Comment: I don't think that *is* true. The only reason to choose `WeakMap` is for memory management effects, which the polyfills do not achieve - by definition, anywhere a polyfill is used, you *will* have memory leaks. I can't think of any acceptable use-case. Better stay away from these.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that both polyfills’ implementation of `WeakRef` holds a strong reference to the target.  A `WeakMap` holds a strong reference to a value as long as someone else holds a strong reference to its key; since the key is the `WeakRef`, this means holding a `WeakRef` strongly will prevent garbage collection of its referent.  Such an implementation is technically correct, the best kind of correct: this is because [the no-op garbage collector is a perfectly valid garbage collector](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203).

The only reason to use `WeakMap` is not for any memory reclamation effects, but for the sake of encapsulation: to ensure the only way a holder of a `WeakRef` can obtain its referent is by calling `WeakRef.prototype.deref`, and cannot access it otherwise; not even by guessing a property name.  An equivalent implementation based on ECMAScript 2021 private field syntax would be as follows:

```js
class WeakRef {
    #target;
    constructor(target) {
        this.#target = target;
    }
    deref() {
        return this.#target;
    }
}
```

However, the point of a polyfill is to be portable to older implementations of ECMAScript, which usually fail to provide the latest syntax.  An alternative would be to make the `deref` method a closure held directly in the object instead of `WeakRef.prototype`, but this would make the implementation *observably* diverge from the specification.

---

Now, if you want an implementation of `WeakRef` that occasionally clears weak references, take a look at [Mathieu Hofman’s shim](https://github.com/mhofman/tc39-weakrefs-shim); it is based on an earlier version of the spec, which is most noticeable with the naming of `FinalizationGroup`.  That shim manages to implement a non-degenerate `WeakRef` in a number of environments, using host-specific APIs for each case.  You can forget about applying it in a browser, though, since browsers will not expose such APIs.  `WeakRef` is not polyfillable in general: the API (or something equivalent in power) must be exposed by the host as a primitive, or it cannot be implemented at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a result of misunderstanding on part of the polyfill authors, please consider writing a bug report.

These approaches indeed keep a strong reference to the object, an implementation which is technically conforming, because the program can't argue that a garbage collector is broken just because it was never observed removing an object. However, to achieve *this* feat would have been much easier: just store the object in a property and don't bother with a `WeakMap` at all.

I think some people naïvely expect that a `WeakMap` has weak references to the *values*, as you observed. I also used to have such misconception before reading the docs carefully. Nevertheless, this would not explain why `WeakMap` has been in the spec since 2015 while `WeakRef` hasn't made it past the proposal stage yet, for over 3 years. Such naïve collection would be like a `Map` of `WeakRefs`, so why would the language not also expose a single one?

Truth is, it is *impossible* to mimic `WeakRef` with `WeakMap` and careful design has been taken to make it so (primarily, that it is not enumerable). Why? While it is perfectly possible to implement this behaviour reliably, the sentiment in the design group is towards determinism and predictability. [This short paragraph](https://w3ctag.github.io/design-principles/#js-gc) summarizes it nicely, with reasoning and an example considered a wrong design past decision. The following two sentences directly preclude *anything* like a `WeakRef`:

> This means that you shouldn’t expose any API that acts as a weak reference, e.g. with a property that becomes null once garbage collection runs. Object and data lifetimes in JavaScript code should be predictable.

With this in mind, in an implementation following the W3C TAG guidelines, not only `WeakMap` can't be used, but not even any *other* approach (which should answer your last question in the comments), except possibly using an ugly and unreliable loophole like that mentioned in the example, for narrowly specific cases. Unless the opinion of the committee changes radically, [the `WeakRef` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs#a-note-of-caution) may never really be standardized. Let's hope that a carefully worded note of caution, as included in the current version, and an appeal to excess memory usage and other interesting and well-founded use cases, will eventually allow such exception.

Comment: Just wanted to add that WeakRef has indeed been standardized in ES2021.