# Understanding this JS WeakRef polyfill implementation

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, weak-references, polyfills

I've came across this WeakRef polyfill: [ungap / weakrefs](https://github.com/ungap/weakrefs/blob/master/index.js).

I'm struggling to understand how it works, particularly at line 11-14:

```js
var wr = new WeakMap;
function WeakRef(value) {
    wr.set(this, value);
}
```

So there is a global WeakMap `wr`.

And a constructor-like function `WeakRef` that takes a `value` and stores it in `wr`, using `this` ([the resulting object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#as_a_constructor)) as key.

My understanding is the `wr` global WeakMap wouldn't drop the inserted `value` until the key is dropped. In this case, the key is the resulting WeakRef object.

So `value` wouldn't be allowed to be GC-ed until the created WeakRef is dropped.

Wouldn't this make the polyfill a **strong** reference?

Comment: It would; your understanding is correct. There's no way to polyfill weak references until the [WeakRef proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs)

Comment: Yep. It is strong reference. How can they call this a polyfill. It's a stub.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are WeakRef polyfills made with WeakMap? I don't see how that can work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140647/why-are-weakref-polyfills-made-with-weakmap-i-dont-see-how-that-can-work)

Answer (score 4):

[It really is strong reference.](https://github.com/ungap/weakrefs/issues/1)

Why couldn't they just mention that in the README. Or maybe atleast leave the issue mentioning this open??